# R: assign values to a column when two other columns match

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Here is my sample data:

```
samp_df <- tibble(id= c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
              event= c(111, 112, 113, 114),
              values = c(23, 12, 45, 60),
              min_value = c(12, 12, 113, 113))
```

I would like to create a column in the dataframe that has the `event` of the min value. So in the example the column would look like: `c(112, 112, 113, 113)`. So the idea is that  I want to take the value from `event` whenever `values` and `min_value` match. It is important that this is also grouped by the id variable.

Here is what I tried, but it's not exactly right as it add NA's instead of the event:

```
samp_df <- samp_df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(event_with_min = if_else(min_value == value,
                                  event, NA_integer_)
```

A dplyr solution would also be optimal!

Comment: Try `mutate(event_with_min = if_else(values == min_value, event, NA_real_))`

Comment: `samp_df$event_with_min <- samp_df$event[samp_df$values==min(samp_df$values)] `

Comment: @Peter This works! However a dplyr solution would be optimal, just for my own personal preference :)

Comment: @Peter I left out of my question that it needs to include a grouping so I've now edited it accordingly.

Comment: I did try for a dplyr solution but I could only find really hacky solutions. I'll have another go as it is quite an interesting problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

samp_df <- tibble(id= c("A", "A", "B", "B"),
                  event= c(111, 112, 113, 114),
                  values = c(23, 12, 45, 60))

samp_df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(min_value = min(values),
         event_with_min = if_else(min_value == values, event, NA_real_)) %>% 
  fill(event_with_min, .direction = "downup")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>   id    event values min_value event_with_min
#>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 A       111     23        12            112
#> 2 A       112     12        12            112
#> 3 B       113     45        45            113
#> 4 B       114     60        45            113
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

I've had to sign up as a guest as I am working on a train. Will revert to own user once back at home! Peter

Comment: Thanks! This looks great, I wasn't aware of the `downup` argument for `fill`. Why, by the way, does `direction`require a full stop before it?

Comment: I've had a think about this overnight. I suspect it is a way to distinguish function inputs from function arguments. The input(s) to the fill function are expected to be variable names (in your case tibble column names), in the tidyverse they are unquoted (i.e. non standard evaluation in other words `event_with_min` rather than "event_with_min") .  In order that the function can distinguish between an input called `direction` and the argument `direction` the argument takes a dot prefix: `.direction` as it is unlikely variables are so constructed. Try `.direction` instead of `event_with_min`!